Does Equipartition hold in overdamped dynamics?
We start with the Langevin equation
$$m\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}x}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}} = -\Gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} +\sqrt{2\Gamma k_{B}T} \eta(t). $$
Now, we know that at $t \gg m/\Gamma$, the velocity degree of freedom relaxes to Maxwell distribution of velocities. Now we neglect inertia term in a viscous medium, and we are left with only the equation of motion of position variable:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} =  \sqrt{\dfrac{2 k_{B}T}{\Gamma}} \eta(t).$$
However, if we calculate $\langle v^{2}(t) \rangle_{equ}$ from the above equation, we get it to be equal to $\frac{2 k_{B}T}{\Gamma}\delta(t)$, which is not $k_{B}T/m$. Now can someone explain this violation?

The velocity is not well defined for an overdamped system and hence the kinetic energy does not exist. But if you have a potential, for example an harmonic one, you have equipartition of potential energy (because you have a well defined position). As you can see from the first equation (it would have the same form of an overdamped system with linear force)

For the overdamped system, the only DOF is $x(t)$, not the full "phase space" coordinate (another way of rephrasing Syrocco's comment): the equation is first order so you only need the initial position, not velocity and position. When the steady state is reached, you should find the Gibbs weight p(x)~exp -U/T for a particle in an external potential U. In the absence of external potential, you may take a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772004/226902
